# Django Search Box not displaying results

Tags: html, django, search

I'm new to coding and working on my class assignment displaying a search box in Django. I was able to display the search box, but the results are not being displayed. In the inspector tool, I do see the search results coming through the GET method so I am assume it must an issue with my HTML code.

I would appreciate any suggestions/resources on how to fix this issue.

[Picture of search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmKE8.png)

```html
{% extends "base_menu.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Ads</h1>

<div style="float:right">
<!-- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_search_button.asp -->
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search"
  {% if search %} value="{{ search }}" {% endif %}
  >
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
<a href="{% url 'ads:all' %}"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
</form>
</div>

<p>
{% if ad_list %}
<ul>

  {% for ad in ad_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'ads:ad_detail'  ad.id %}">{{ ad.title }}</a>
        {% if ad.owner == user %}
        (<a href="{% url 'ads:ad_update' ad.id %}">Edit</a> |
        <a href="{% url 'ads:ad_delete' ad.id %}">Delete</a>)
        {% endif %}
    </li>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <!-- Two hrefs with two stacked icons each - one showing and one hidden -->
        <a href="#" onclick=
            "favPost('{% url 'ads:ad_unfavorite' ad.id %}', {{ ad.id }});return false;"
            {% if ad.id not in favorites %} style="display: none;" {% endif %}
            id="favorite_star_{{ad.id}}">
        <span class="fa-stack" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x" style="color: orange;"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
        <!-- the second href -->
        <a href="#" onclick=
             "favPost('{% url 'ads:ad_favorite' ad.id %}', {{ ad.id }} );return false;"
            {% if ad.id in favorites %} style="display: none;" {% endif %}
            id="unfavorite_star_{{ad.id}}">
        <span class="fa-stack" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x" style="display: none; color: orange;"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
        {% endif %}


  {% endfor %}


</ul>
{% else %}
  <p>There are no ads in the database.</p>
{% endif %}
</p>
<p>
<a href="{% url 'ads:ad_create' %}">Add an Ad</a> |
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={% url 'ads:all' %}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={% url 'ads:all' %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
</p>



<script>
function favPost(url, ad_id) {
    console.log('Requesting JSON');
    $.post(url, {},  function(rowz){
        console.log(url, 'finished');
        $("#unfavorite_star_"+ad_id).toggle();
        $("#favorite_star_"+ad_id).toggle();
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
        alert('Url failed with '+xhr.status+' '+url);
    });
}
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your html looks fine. Can you add your ListView to make sure the search query is being processed correctly?